# Binary Search Tree in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, binary-search

I have written this code for Binary Search tree. Help me to improve this code using C++11 and C++14. Where to use functions like `minimum()` `maximum()` `predecessor()` `successor()` `insertValue(Args&&.. args)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree
{
  struct Node
  {
    T data;
    Node* parent;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    Node(T const& value) : data(value),
                           parent(nullptr),
                           leftChild(nullptr),
                           rightChild(nullptr)
                           {}
    //move constructor
    //It  moves the content of 'value' into the node
    Node(T&& value) : data(std::move(value)),
                      parent(nullptr),
                      leftChild(nullptr),
                      rightChild(nullptr)
                      {}
    //to enter any number and type of arguments
    template<typename... Args>
    Node(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                           parent(nullptr),
                           leftChild(nullptr),
                           rightChild(nullptr)
                           {}

    ~Node()
    {
      delete leftChild;
      delete rightChild;
    }
  };

public:
  Node* root;
  BinaryTree() : root(nullptr) {}
  BinaryTree(BinaryTree const&)            = delete;
  BinaryTree& operator=(BinaryTree const&) = delete;
  ~BinaryTree()
  {
    delete root;
  }

  bool isEmpty() const
  {
    return root == nullptr;
  }

  void insertValue(T const& value)
  {
    Node* node = new Node(value);
    Node* tmp;
    node->leftChild = nullptr;
    node->rightChild = nullptr;
    node->parent = nullptr;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
      root = node;
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      Node* current = root;
      while(current)
      {
        tmp = current;
        if(node->data > current->data)
          current = current->rightChild;
        else current = current->leftChild;
      }

      if(node->data < tmp->data)
        tmp->leftChild = node;
      else tmp->rightChild = node;

      node->parent = tmp;
    }
  }

  void insertValue(T&& value)
  {
    Node* node = new Node(std::move(value));
    Node* tmp;
    node->leftChild = nullptr;
    node->rightChild = nullptr;
    node->parent = nullptr;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
       root = node;
       return;
    }
    else
    {
      Node* current = root;
      while(current)
      {
        tmp = current;
        if(node->data > current->data)
          current = current->rightChild;
        else current = current->leftChild;
      }

      if(node->data < tmp->data)
        tmp->leftChild = node;
      else tmp->rightChild = node;

      node->parent = tmp;
    }
  }

  template<typename... Args>
  void insertValue(Args&&... args)
  {
    Node* tmp;
    Node* node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    node->leftChild = nullptr;
    node->rightChild = nullptr;
    node->parent = nullptr;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
      root = node;
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      Node* current = root;
      while(current)
      {
        tmp = current;
        if(node->data > current->data)
          current = current->rightChild;
        else current = current->leftChild;
      }

      if(node->data < tmp->data)
        tmp->leftChild = node;
      else tmp->rightChild = node;

      node->parent = tmp;
    }
  }

    void deleteValue(T value, Node* node)
    {
      if(!node)
        return;
      if(node->data < value)
        deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
      else if(node->data > value)
        deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
      else
      {
        if(node->leftChild == nullptr && node->rightChild == nullptr)
        {
          if(node->parent == nullptr)
          {
            root = nullptr;
            delete node;
            return;
          }
          else if(node->parent->leftChild  == node)
          {
            node->parent->leftChild = nullptr;
            delete node;
            return;
          }
          else
          {
            node->parent->rightChild = nullptr;
            delete node;
            return;
          }
        }

        if(node->rightChild != nullptr)
        {
          T temp = node->data;
          node->data = node->rightChild->data;
          node->rightChild->data = temp;
          deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
          return;
        }
        if(node->leftChild != nullptr)
        {
          T temp = node->data;
          node->data = node->leftChild->data;
          node->leftChild->data = temp;
          deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    void deleteValue(T value)
    {
      deleteValue(value, root);
    }
    void inOrder(Node* node)
    {
      if(node != nullptr)
      {
        inOrder(node->leftChild);
        std::cout << " " << node->data;
        inOrder(node->rightChild);
      }
      else return;
    }

    void preOrder(Node* node)
    {
      if(node != nullptr)
      {
        std::cout << " " << node->data;
        if(node->leftChild) preOrder(node->leftChild);
        if(node->rightChild) preOrder(node->rightChild);
      }
      else return;
    }

    void postOrder(Node* node)
    {
      if(node != nullptr)
      {
        if(node->leftChild) postOrder(node->leftChild);
        if(node->rightChild) postOrder(node->rightChild);
        std::cout << " " << node->data;
      }
      else return;
    }

  void print_inOrder()
  {
    inOrder(root);
  }

  void print_preOrder()
  {
    preOrder(root);
  }

  void print_postOrder()
  {
    postOrder(root);
  }

private:

  Node* search(Node* root, T value) const
  {
    if(root == nullptr || value == root->data)
      return root;

    if(value < root->data)
      return search(root->leftChild, value);

    else
      return search(root->rightChild, value);
  }

  Node* minimum(Node* root)
  {
      while(root->leftChild != nullptr)
          root = root->leftChild;
      return root;
  }

  Node* maximum(Node* root)
  {
      while(root->rightChild != nullptr)
          root = root->rightChild;
      return root;
  }

  //Successor - a node which has the next higher key
  Node* successor(Node* node)
  {
      if(node->rightChild != nullptr)
        return minimum(node->rightChild);

      Node* temp = node->parent;

      while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->rightChild)
      {
          node = temp;
          temp = temp->parent;
      }
      return temp;
  }

  //Predecessor - a node which has the next lower key
  Node* predecessor(Node* node)
  {
      if(node->leftChild != nullptr)
        return maximum(node->leftChild);

      Node* temp = node->parent;

      while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->leftChild)
      {
          node = temp;
          temp = temp->parent;
      }
      return temp;
  }

};

int main()
{
  BinaryTree<int> bt1;
  bt1.insertValue(100);
  bt1.insertValue(20);
  bt1.insertValue(30);
  bt1.insertValue(400);
  bt1.insertValue(50);
  std::cout << "In Order: ";
  bt1.print_inOrder();
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout << "Pre Order: ";
  bt1.print_preOrder();
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout << "Post Order: ";
  bt1.print_postOrder();
  std::cout << "\nDeleting 20 ";
  bt1.deleteValue(20);
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout << "In Order: ";
  bt1.print_inOrder();
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout << "Pre Order: ";
  bt1.print_preOrder();
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout << "Post Order: ";
  bt1.print_postOrder();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing an in order iterator for it? You could implement others too, and make a function which would return a range. You could as well make it mandatory, so that it will be obvious which kind of traversal is going on.

Comment: Have you considered foregoing pointers in favor of `std::optional<std::ref<Node>>`s? It's technically C++17 but C++14 has `std::experimental::optional`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer makes some excellent suggestions. I won't repeat them here.

### You have a bug in `insertValue`

You don't have any checks to make sure that a value is not inserted twice.

If I use

```
bt1.insertValue(20);
bt1.insertValue(20);
```

`insertValue` gladly inserts 20 twice into the tree. A simple update to `insertValue` will fix that.

```
void insertValue(T const& value)
{
   // If the value is already there, don't insert it.
   if ( search(root, value) != nullptr )
   {
      return;
   }

   // Rest of your code.
}
```

### Make `Node` a `private` `struct` of `BinaryTree`

`Node` does not need to be exposed to users of `BinaryTree`. It's best to make it a `private` `struct` of the class.

### Don't hard code `std::cout` as the sole target to output `BinaryTree`

It will be better to provide an `operator<<` function to output `BinaryTree`.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, BinaryTree cons& t)
{
  // Do the needful to print t.
  return out;
}
```

After that, you could use:

```
std::cout << bt1 << std::endl;
```

That will also allow you to print a `BinaryTree` to any `std::ostream`.

### Use manipulator in the spirit of the standard library

Instead of using

```
 bt1.print_preOrder();
```

you can use something like:

```
 std::cout << setprintorder(PreOrder) << bt1 << endl;
```

To print the a `BinaryTree` in "in order" and "post order" style, you can use:

```
 std::cout << setprintorder(InOrder) << bt1 << endl;
 std::cout << setprintorder(PostOrder) << bt1 << endl;
```

You will need some supporting code to pull that off.

Here's my simple attempt to support that:

```
enum BinaryTreePrintOrder {InOrder, PreOrder, PostOrder};
struct BinaryTreeManipulator { BinaryTreePrintOrder o; };
static BinaryTreeManipulator m;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, BinaryTreeManipulator )
{
   // This function does not do anything. It just allows
   // for syntactic form similar to the manipulators in the
   // standard library.
   return out;
}

BinaryTreeManipulator& setprintorder(BinaryTreePrintOrder o)
{
   m.o = o;
   return m;
}

BinaryTreePrintOrder getprintorder()
{
   return m.o;
}
```

and then, in the `operator<<` function, you can use:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, BinaryTree const& t)
{
   if ( getprintorder() == InOrder )
   {
      t.inOrder(t.root, out);
   }
   else if ( getprintorder() == PreOrder )
   {
      t.preOrder(t.root, out);
   }
   else
   {
      t.postOrder(t.root, out);
   }
   return out;
}
```

### Make the `printXXX` functions `const` member functions

Without that the `operator<<` function won't work.

---

Here's an updated version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

enum BinaryTreePrintOrder {InOrder, PreOrder, PostOrder};
struct BinaryTreeManipulator { BinaryTreePrintOrder o; };
static BinaryTreeManipulator m;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, BinaryTreeManipulator )
{
   return out;
}

BinaryTreeManipulator& setprintorder(BinaryTreePrintOrder o)
{
   m.o = o;
   return m;
}

BinaryTreePrintOrder getprintorder()
{
   return m.o;
}

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree
{
   private:

      struct Node
      {
         T data;
         Node* parent;
         Node* leftChild;
         Node* rightChild;
         Node(T const& value) : data(value),
         parent(nullptr),
         leftChild(nullptr),
         rightChild(nullptr)
         {}
         //move constructor
         //It  moves the content of 'value' into the node
         Node(T&& value) : data(std::move(value)),
         parent(nullptr),
         leftChild(nullptr),
         rightChild(nullptr)
         {}
         //to enter any number and type of arguments
         template<typename... Args>
            Node(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
            parent(nullptr),
            leftChild(nullptr),
            rightChild(nullptr)
         {}

         ~Node()
         {
            delete leftChild;
            delete rightChild;
         }
      };

   public:
      Node* root;
      BinaryTree() : root(nullptr) {}
      BinaryTree(BinaryTree const&)            = delete;
      BinaryTree& operator=(BinaryTree const&) = delete;
      ~BinaryTree()
      {
         delete root;
      }

      bool isEmpty() const
      {
         return root == nullptr;
      }

      void insertValue(T const& value)
      {
         // If the value is already there, don't insert it.
         if ( search(root, value) != nullptr )
         {
            return;
         }

         Node* node = new Node(value);
         Node* tmp;
         node->leftChild = nullptr;
         node->rightChild = nullptr;
         node->parent = nullptr;

         if(isEmpty())
         {
            root = node;
            return;
         }
         else
         {
            Node* current = root;
            while(current)
            {
               tmp = current;
               if(node->data > current->data)
                  current = current->rightChild;
               else current = current->leftChild;
            }

            if(node->data < tmp->data)
               tmp->leftChild = node;
            else tmp->rightChild = node;

            node->parent = tmp;
         }
      }

      void insertValue(T&& value)
      {
         // If the value is already there, don't insert it.
         if ( search(root, value) != nullptr )
         {
            return;
         }

         Node* node = new Node(std::move(value));
         Node* tmp;
         node->leftChild = nullptr;
         node->rightChild = nullptr;
         node->parent = nullptr;

         if(isEmpty())
         {
            root = node;
            return;
         }
         else
         {
            Node* current = root;
            while(current)
            {
               tmp = current;
               if(node->data > current->data)
                  current = current->rightChild;
               else current = current->leftChild;
            }

            if(node->data < tmp->data)
               tmp->leftChild = node;
            else tmp->rightChild = node;

            node->parent = tmp;
         }
      }

      template<typename... Args>
         void insertValue(Args&&... args)
         {
            Node* tmp;
            Node* node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            node->leftChild = nullptr;
            node->rightChild = nullptr;
            node->parent = nullptr;

            if(isEmpty())
            {
               root = node;
               return;
            }
            else
            {
               Node* current = root;
               while(current)
               {
                  tmp = current;
                  if(node->data > current->data)
                     current = current->rightChild;
                  else current = current->leftChild;
               }

               if(node->data < tmp->data)
                  tmp->leftChild = node;
               else tmp->rightChild = node;

               node->parent = tmp;
            }
         }

      void deleteValue(T value, Node* node)
      {
         if(!node)
            return;
         if(node->data < value)
            deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
         else if(node->data > value)
            deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
         else
         {
            if(node->leftChild == nullptr && node->rightChild == nullptr)
            {
               if(node->parent == nullptr)
               {
                  root = nullptr;
                  delete node;
                  return;
               }
               else if(node->parent->leftChild  == node)
               {
                  node->parent->leftChild = nullptr;
                  delete node;
                  return;
               }
               else
               {
                  node->parent->rightChild = nullptr;
                  delete node;
                  return;
               }
            }

            if(node->rightChild != nullptr)
            {
               T temp = node->data;
               node->data = node->rightChild->data;
               node->rightChild->data = temp;
               deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
               return;
            }
            if(node->leftChild != nullptr)
            {
               T temp = node->data;
               node->data = node->leftChild->data;
               node->leftChild->data = temp;
               deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
               return;
            }
         }
      }

      void deleteValue(T value)
      {
         deleteValue(value, root);
      }

      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, BinaryTree const& t)
      {
         if ( getprintorder() == InOrder )
         {
            t.inOrder(t.root, out);
         }
         else if ( getprintorder() == PreOrder )
         {
            t.preOrder(t.root, out);
         }
         else
         {
            t.postOrder(t.root, out);
         }

         return out;
      }


      void print_inOrder(std::ostream& out) const
      {
         inOrder(root, out);
      }

      void print_preOrder(std::ostream& out) const
      {
         preOrder(root, out);
      }

      void print_postOrder(std::ostream& out) const
      {
         postOrder(root, out);
      }

      void inOrder(Node* node, std::ostream& out) const
      {
         if(node != nullptr)
         {
            inOrder(node->leftChild, out);
            out << " " << node->data;
            inOrder(node->rightChild, out);
         }
      }

      void preOrder(Node* node, std::ostream& out) const
      {
         if(node != nullptr)
         {
            out << " " << node->data;
            if(node->leftChild) preOrder(node->leftChild, out);
            if(node->rightChild) preOrder(node->rightChild, out);
         }
      }

      void postOrder(Node* node, std::ostream& out) const
      {
         if(node != nullptr)
         {
            if(node->leftChild) postOrder(node->leftChild, out);
            if(node->rightChild) postOrder(node->rightChild, out);
            out << " " << node->data;
         }
      }

      Node* search(Node* root, T value) const
      {
         if(root == nullptr || value == root->data)
            return root;

         if(value < root->data)
            return search(root->leftChild, value);

         else
            return search(root->rightChild, value);
      }

      Node* minimum(Node* root)
      {
         while(root->leftChild != nullptr)
            root = root->leftChild;
         return root;
      }

      Node* maximum(Node* root)
      {
         while(root->rightChild != nullptr)
            root = root->rightChild;
         return root;
      }

      //Successor - a node which has the next higher key
      Node* successor(Node* node)
      {
         if(node->rightChild != nullptr)
            return minimum(node->rightChild);

         Node* temp = node->parent;

         while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->rightChild)
         {
            node = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
         }
         return temp;
      }

      //Predecessor - a node which has the next lower key
      Node* predecessor(Node* node)
      {
         if(node->leftChild != nullptr)
            return maximum(node->leftChild);

         Node* temp = node->parent;

         while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->leftChild)
         {
            node = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
         }
         return temp;
      }
};


int main()
{
   BinaryTree<int> bt1;
   bt1.insertValue(100);
   bt1.insertValue(20);
   bt1.insertValue(20);
   bt1.insertValue(30);
   bt1.insertValue(400);
   bt1.insertValue(50);

   std::cout << "In Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(InOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Pre Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(PreOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Post Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(PostOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;

   std::cout << "Deleting 20 ";
   bt1.deleteValue(20);
   std::cout<<"\n";

   std::cout << "In Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(InOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Pre Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(PreOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Post Order: ";
   std::cout << setprintorder(PostOrder) << bt1 << std::endl;
}
```

and its output:

```
In Order:  20 30 50 100 400
Pre Order:  100 20 30 50 400
Post Order:  50 30 20 400 100
Deleting 20 
In Order:  30 50 100 400
Pre Order:  100 30 50 400
Post Order:  50 30 400 100
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is very easy to read! Your naming is quite good, and it's very clear what's going on in each function. Here are some things I'd improve:

## Don't Repeat Yourself

I notice in all 3 of the `insertValue()` methods, you're setting the newly created node's parent, and left and right children to `nullptr`. You've already done that in the constructor for `Node`, so there's no reason to also do it in `insertValue()`. Also, the body of each `insertValue()` function is identical except for the call to create the new `Node`. You should factor that out into a separate method.

Likewise, you have public functions for `inOrder()`, `preOrder()`, and `postOrder()`, but then you created wrapper methods for `print_inOrder()`, `print_preOrder()`, and `print_postOrder()` that literally do nothing other than call the other corresponding methods. If that's all the functionality you need, then I'd remove the `print*` ones and rename the other ones to `print*`. (Also, it's a bit odd that you're mixing both CamelCase and use of underscores in the names of `print_*`. Pick one or the other.)

I do think there's a valid case for having both sets of functions. That would be if the generically named ones took either a function pointer or lambda to do something to each node as it traversed the tree. Then the `print_*` methods could call it with a function or lambda that simply prints out the value, and they could be reused for other things if you have that need.

## Don't Make Functions Private If They're Not Used

I'm unclear on what you're trying to accomplish with `search()`, `minimum()`, `maximum()` et al. You ask:

> Where to use functions like `minimum()` `maximum()` `predecessor()` `successor()` `insertValue(Args&&.. args)`

That's up to you! If you think users of this class have a use for them, I'd make them public. But that's going to depend entirely on how the class will be used. I think they're potentially useful functions.

## Errors

Your `minimum()`, `maximum()`, `successor()` and `predecessor()` methods don't check to see if the passed-in `Node` is `nullptr`. That can lead to a crash if they're called on an empty tree.

## Early Returns

I'm not a huge fan of early returns. I think they tend to make the code harder to reason about and have the potential to introduce hard-to-detect errors. For something like `deletValue()`, I'd probably leave the first one for `if (!node)`, but I'd rewrite the large chain of `if` statements in the last block to not need a return statement. Something like this:

```
void deleteValue(T value, Node* node)
{
  if(!node)
  {
    return;
  }

  if(node->data < value)
  {
    deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
  }
  else if(node->data > value)
  {
    deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
  }
  else if(node->leftChild == nullptr && node->rightChild == nullptr)
  {
      if(node->parent == nullptr)
      {
        root = nullptr;
        delete node;
      }
      else if(node->parent->leftChild  == node)
      {
        node->parent->leftChild = nullptr;
        delete node;
      }
      else
      {
        node->parent->rightChild = nullptr;
        delete node;
      }
  }
  else if(node->rightChild != nullptr)
  {
      T temp = node->data;
      node->data = node->rightChild->data;
      node->rightChild->data = temp;
      deleteValue(value, node->rightChild);
  }
  else if(node->leftChild != nullptr)
  {
      T temp = node->data;
      node->data = node->leftChild->data;
      node->leftChild->data = temp;
      deleteValue(value, node->leftChild);
  }
}
```

## Nitpicks

This is something minor that doesn't really affect the running of the program, but in `inOrder()`, `preOrder()` and `postOrder()`, you don't need to put a `return` in the else clause. You can just leave off the `else` and the return will happen anyway.